# Decryption with PublicKey of Smartcard Certificate

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, smartcard, x509certificate2

I'm currently using a smartcard from a German project to secure/encrypt certain data of cash register systems (called INSIKA, if there is anyone that knows about this). The smartcard contains a certificate with an unkonwkn private key to encrypt and a public key to decrypt data. The data can be encrypted using functionality of the smartcard itself. Unfortunately there is no such method for the decryption of the encrypted data.

The INISKA documentation mentions, that I should be able to read the certificate stored on the smartcard and get the public key that I can use to actually decrypt the pdata myselfe. But somehow I cannot find a proper way to do this. Using the smartcard I get:

- A byte array containing the raw data of the certificate
- A X509Certificate2 instance using the constructor of this class and the raw data
- A public key byte array using the GetPublicKey() method of the certificate instance
- The property PublicKey containing some information like Oid or an AlgorithmId

Most of my search results so far have suggested that I should use some code that looks like the following:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) certificate.PublicKey.Key;
byte[] decryptedData = provider.Decrypt(signature.SignatureByteArray, false);
```

However accessing the .Key property throws a NotSupportedException with the message "**The certificate key algorithm is not supported.**". The certificates PublicKey.Oid property contains the information that the public key algorithm is ECC (ecliptic curve cryptography)

Does anybody have any suggestions what I can do to decrypt the data i managed to encrypt using the information I have? Is it possible that I am missing some part of the certificate or some needed functionality to select the correct key algorithm? Is there another way to use the public key (e.g. the byte array) to manually instantiate some decryption class (all example codes I have found require some information that I do not have or do not know where to get like modulus or exponent)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can always read the entire certificate and dump it into a file. Then open it in Windows and it will show all properties of the certificate, aka: keys, types of keys, encryption type, thumbprint ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *decrypt* signatures. You can only *verify* them. Decryption and verification are different concepts and PKCS#1 compatible RSA uses different padding mechanisms - and of course different keys - for both.

Please take a look at the `VerifyData` and `VerifyHash` methods of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instead. You cannot decrypt a signature (and if you could you would just get back the *one-way-hash* value, not the data, in 99% of the cases).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was already expecting such kind of an answer due to my latest researches today. I think I misunderstood or misinterpreted some parts of the INSIKA concept (because they were talking about asymmetrical cryptography).

However I still am not sure how to get a correct RSACryptoServiceProvider since my PublicKey.Key property of the certificate is always unavailable because of the NotSupportedException. I'm still missing something here...

Comment: Uh oh, I think I know what it is. You're trying to use a Brainpool curve that's not supported by .NET. .NET only supports NIST curves. You may need another library (Bouncy Castle maybe). And obviously you cannot cast it to an RSA based class type. ECC and RSA are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I will try to get a look at bouncy castle. I already found this library but haven't had the time to actually try it out. Maybe it will help me in achieving my goal!